# Disable spring method caching through external property

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I configured spring method caching with ehcache and annotation driven configuration.

I would like however to be able to disable it from a configuration file we use in the application.

My first idea was to call `net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.CacheManager()` with no arguments if method caching is disabled. This throws exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: loadCaches must not return an empty Collection
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:268)
at org.springframework.cache.support.AbstractCacheManager.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractCacheManager.java:49)
```

My second idea was to configure the `net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.CacheManager()` with default data so that the cache is not used (maxElementsInMemory 0 etc.). But then the cache is still used, which is not what I want.

There is a property `net.sf.ehcache.disabled` but I do not want do disable hibernate caching that also uses ehcache.

`Q` How can I configure everything to have spring method caching but disable it from my external configuration file? I do not want to modify the application-context nor the code to enable/disable method caching. Only the configuration file we use in the application can be modified.

Comment: How do you enable the spring Caching functionaltiy, by xml?  Do you use Spring 3.1?

Comment: I use spring 3.1 with annotation driven cache as explained in the doc http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I was looking for was `NoOpCacheManager`:

To make it work I switched from xml bean creation to a factory

I did something as follows:

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    final CacheManager cacheManager;        
    if (this.methodCacheManager != null) {
        final EhCacheCacheManager ehCacheCacheManager = new EhCacheCacheManager();
        ehCacheCacheManager.setCacheManager(this.methodCacheManager);
        cacheManager = ehCacheCacheManager;
    } else {
        cacheManager = new NoOpCacheManager();
    }

    return cacheManager;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [spring profile](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/), to enable (or not) the spring caching support

```
<beans profile="withCache">
   <cache:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

Comment: I tried that solution but I do not manage to programatically test my cache flags and then turn on the cache profiles without refreshing the context.